# Are request for resource list questions going to be acceptable?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[What are some good resources for improving communication skills?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/972/what-are-some-good-resources-for-improving-communication-skills)

It is an on topic request I think but in general I dislike the list requests.  They are ripe for piling on and there is no one right answer.

So the question is: Are we going to allow them, and the potential blight they bring with them, here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My inclination is *NO*, for all the reasons you've mentioned, plus the fact that questions asking for a list of "things" are really just a variation on [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) which are pretty much universally awful.

A question asking about techniques, methods, procedures, policies, etc. to address a specific problem are a better way to ask these kinds of questions, and the answers can include references to relevant resources (as long as they *answer the question* and [are not just a link to some external resource](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers))

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Basically, I think a "How can I do X" question is always going to be better than "What are some resources for X", and may still get some of the same resource links but with more full answers.

Comment: I am ok with a request for references to specific studies since generally they are a much smaller dataset assuming its not something like anything that every had to do with the workplace.  Generally the question should be focused on a specific problem and have a reason for needing the reference.  IE to provide as support to management per their process.

Comment: `Focused question` or `specific problem` is not sufficient condition. See [this](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/889/is-there-a-canonical-reference-for-technical-resumes) question for example. Not quite useful.

Comment: @Chad It depends on the question, but I'm generally OK with someone stating in their question that they would like some kind of evidence/study/etc. to back up answers (like you said, you often need it to convince your manager you're right).  In some cases though *questions on Workplace* might actually become the references, especially if the site does well :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is usually site to site differing. I think [DSP.SE allows](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68/asking-for-book-suggestions-on-topic) this, where as in the [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/are-book-recommendations-on-topic) it is considered not-constructive.

This looks like an apparent contradiction but the utility might change. In case of DSP, one is usually referring to set of papers - and doing google search for papers even if easy, only when someone has read some of these paper himself/herself does it make sense to recommend. No one really reads tons of research papers unless you are following some citations or special recommendations - so this makes perfect sense here.

In case of Programmers.Se -if i ask `what is your favorite book on design pattern?` and you know you are now beating the Amazon's recommendation engine. It's just waste of time there. Though it is not completely banned there as well, it depends on the [questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=Book).

So essentially, for every site value of these references do make a difference.

In case of workplace, i think we are dealing with generalized subject matter even more than programmers; so allowing "my favorite books is ____" will collect huge crowd but not value.

Comment: If you ask "what is your favorite book on design pattern?", you'll get an onslaught of down votes, but if you ask ["Is there a canonical book on design patterns?"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/124109/is-there-a-canonical-book-on-design-patterns) you'd be on topic (ok, if you ask it now it'd be closed as a dupe). We welcome [some book questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/are-book-recommendations-on-topic), but they have to be about specialized topics, not just what's your favourite...

Comment: My big problem with lists is when they get out of date.  Some "give me a reference" questions will never have that problem (the way *K&R* is ***THE*** reference book for C, or *Parkinson's Law* is/should be required reading for all managers), others will.  Solid references are an exception to the guideline.